# JS - Splitting a string and looping through results

Tags: javascript

In JS, I'm having trouble working out how to split a string coming from an AJAX call.

This is what I have so far:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
feedUpdateResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
/////...split script.../////
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://myDomain.com/myScript.aspx",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Where you have /////...split script...///// in my script above, I need to add a little function that splits the string returned from my AJAX call.

The string simply contains names of DIVs, like this:

```
feedUpdateResponse = "div1/div2/div3/div4"
```

I would like to first split the string by its slashes (/) and run a loop through the different values and do stuff to those elements on my page.

To give an idea of what I need to achieve, I have given this example which is a mix of ASP & JS - it's the only way I can possibly describe it (and show that I've had an attempt) :)

```
MyArray = Split(feedUpdateResponse,"/")
For Each X In MyArray
documentGetElementById('updateAvailable_'+x).style.visibility="visible";
Next
```

On my page I have an ASP script that produces jquery carousels, all contained by separate DIVs. The DIVs are named DIV1, DIV2 etc. Inside DIV1, for example, is a text element called `updateAvailable_div1` which will alert the user "There are new photos available for this feed, please click the refresh button".

Could somebody please explain to me how I can change my example above to work in JS? Just need to split the string into an array and loop through the split values...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion there but really don't understand it sorry

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split a string on a specified character with the results returned as an array. So then it's just a matter of looping through the array:

```
// given your existing variable
// feedUpdateResponse = "div1/div2/div3/div4" as set in the
// code in the question, add this:

var a = feedUpdateResponse.split("/"),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("updateAvailable_" + a[i]).style.visibility
                                                                 = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 47):

Get your array via `string.split("/")`.  Iterate your array using your method of choice.  I prefer [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
feedUpdateResponse.split("/").forEach(function (item) {
    document.getElementById(item).style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

See the [compatibility notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) for using `.forEach()` in older browsers.

Comment: Jeeez, IE causes problems again! Only IE9 supports FOREACH(), so not sure I can use this. 17% of my users are, annoyingly, still using IE8..., 7% are still on IE7. Thanks though Gilly3

Comment: @martin - see the last sentence of my answer. That link provides an implementation for older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative:

```
for(element of feedUpdateResponse.split("/")){
    do_your_thing();
}
```

Using `for..in` will end up giving you the indices on the array (keys), while `for..of` will give you the elements of the array (values).

You can also do:

```
for ([index, element] of Object.entries(feedUpdateResponse.split("/"))) {
    do_your_thing();
}
```

In the event that you need the index.

The disadvantage is it not being compatible with IE, but for personal projects or a quick automation script it usually does me plenty fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var a = feedUpdateResponse.split("/");

for (i in a) {
    document.getElementById("updateAvailable_" + a[i]).style.visibility
                                                                 = "visible";
}
```

Comment: To quote gilly3's comment from the pre-edit version of John's answer: "Do not iterate arrays with for .. in loops". Please use either `.forEach()` or a traditional for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var feedUpdateResponse = "div1/div2/div3/div4";
var feedUpdateSplit = feedUpdateResponse.split("/");

for (var x = 0; x < feedUpdateSplit.length; x++) {
  document.getElementById("updateAvailable_" + feedUpdateSplit[x]).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Do not iterate arrays with `for .. in` loops.