# How to populate multiples Checkboxes while edit in this scenario?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have set the Checkboxes in HTML like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="mincheck[]" name="mincheck[]" value="a" />a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="mincheck[]" name="mincheck[]" value="b" />b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="mincheck[]" name="mincheck[]" value="c" />c</label>
```

On clicking the edit button, I have a jquery function that populates data in the modal. All the data are populated except the checkboxes.

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
    var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_single.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{user_id:user_id},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#modal-dialog').modal('show');
            $('#user_form')[0].reset();
            $('#fullname').val(data.fullname);
            $('#datetimepicker1').val(data.visit_date);
            $('#user_uploaded_image').html(data.user_image);

            **{how do I write the code here to populate the Checkboxes}**

            $('.modal-title').text("Edit Client");
            $('#user_id').val(user_id);
            $('#action').val("Edit");
            $('#operation').val("Edit");
        }
    });
});
```

**Note: I have inserted all the checkboxes values in a single column in the table by concatenating all the values like this;**

```
if(!empty($_POST['mincheck'])){
    $checkbox_values = '"'.implode(',', $_POST['mincheck']).'"';
}
```

And my server-side code for fetching data is as follows,

```
$output = array();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."' 
LIMIT 1");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $output["fullname"] = $row["fullname"];
    **{how do I fetch checkboxes data here}**
    $output["visit_date"] = $row["visit_date"];
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Can you please post your result and the expected output.

Comment: @Artistic Phoenix

Comment: @Bluetree checkboxes not checked at all while edit... I need the checkboxes to be checked while editing.

Comment: Editing what? A textfield?

Comment: @Vaibhav Bhavsar some suggestion here would be appreciated..

Comment: Same ID for all checkbox hummm /

Comment: @Bluetree the edit form not only contains textfield but also contains checkboxes as i mentioned at the top in question above. All the textfields and dropdown are populated with the data but not checkboxes, hope i made you clear..

Comment: (1) in php, just return the column value same as the others. (2) in your ajax, use `.split()` to explode to an array and loop over the values (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394163/js-splitting-a-string-and-looping-through-results). (3) set the checkboxes in the loop by the array values (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937350/find-checkboxes-by-value-with-javascript)

Comment: @ShreeKhanal lah shree boro suggestion dim ta k garda hola :)

Comment: @Sean thank you for your precious suggestion, but I am new to ajax, so how do i call the individual checkbox, can u please elaborate?

Comment: @Sean wanna thank you once again...you are a savior man... I did this way...
var check= data.documents_received;

if(check.includes("aa")){
    $("input:checkbox[value='Citizenship']").attr("checked", true);
    }

And similarly that worked like magic for all the checkboxes...thank you once again...